# Display a list of Wordpress posts in JQuery Mobile app

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile

I'm experimenting with making my first JQuery Mobile app. I want to have three buttons that when each of them is pressed displays a new page with a summary list of Wordpress blog posts from 3 different categories.

For example:

```
Button 1 link- mysite.com/?cat=1
Button 2 link- mysite.com/?cat=2
Button 3 link- mysite.com/?cat=3
```

So if I press 'Button 1' a new page loads that lists posts from category 1. Each post is in summary format (image thumbnail and brief text). Then clicking this goes through to the full detail version of the blog post.

Would it be done with RSS feeds? I've seen JSON mentioned but have no idea how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to this!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a separate theme that generates HTML that jQuery Mobile can use. Depending on your level of ambition for this project, you could create your own or try to find one online.

Googling 'jquery mobile wordpress theme' returned some promising results, but jQuery Mobile has been changing a lot in the past year, so be aware that these themes might not be compatible with the latest version.

If you plan on creating your own theme, I suggest using one of the default themes as a starting point. At the minimum, you will have to convert:

- index.php (to load jQuery Mobile's CSS and Javascript)
- category.php (for the list-view)
- single.php (for the detail-view)

to use jQuery Mobile markup, as well as the template for the page on which you plan on including the links to the categories (page.php?).

RSS and JSON are unfitting formats for this problem, as jQuery Mobile relies on HTML-markup to render pages.